# Maven different output with different version

Tags: maven, version

My concerned part of the `pom.xml` is

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.14</version>
    </dependency>
```

The maven assembly plugin is used to make the build, which also copies some shell scripts to the target folder. I am able to build this successfully with all files getting copied at proper location in target directory with maven version `Apache Maven 2.1.0 (r755702; 2009-03-19 00:40:27+0530)`. I verified this twice.

#### Problem

Our team uses a Jenkins server to build it for release, which uses `Apache Maven 2.2.1 (r801777; 2009-08-06 20:16:01+0100)`. The build on this too exits with `Build Successfull` message, and does create the main project jar. But the above stated `servlet api` jar and the shell scripts are not getting copied to the desired location.

So, what is the change I need here to make, so that the files get copied as they are getting with `2.1.0` ?
Does anyone know of any difference between these 2 versions of maven in this respect i.e. `2.1.0`and `2.2.1` ?

Comment: First a servlet-api should never end up the resulting archive (war etc.), cause usually this is of scope provided. Furthermore you shouldn't call assembly:assembly you should simply call mvn package to result in a correctly packaged result.

Comment: I agree with your first point. Regarding the 2nd, there are lot of other scripts and file permission to be handled which are taken care by the assembly plugin.

Comment: Yes of course but what is the relationship with calling mvn package instead of mvn assembly:assemble ? If you correctly configured the maven-assembly-plugin there shouldn't be a issue.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this, silly mistake from my side.

I overlooked the global configuration of jenkins. The goals that was being executed by jenkins was `clean install`, which should have been `assembly:assembly`, that results in build as expected.

Keeping this post as is, may be some other mtk will come again in future with same query ;)